# Autoscrolling text animation in CSS not going all the way

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-animations

I'm trying to scroll some **single-line** labels in a **single-line** fixed-width container.
What I've tried so far is:

1. Create a container with fixed dimensions.
2. Place a scrollable container inside and attach the animation.
3. Place the labels.

The animation partially works, but the scrolling doesn't go all the way to what is configured (`translateX(-100%)`).
The overflowing part (green color in codepen) that exceeds the fixed container width is ignored.
I've tried various display and flex field combinations, but noting.

Here is a codepen sample.
https://codepen.io/efthymiosks/pen/QWQGVGg

Comment: One way to get smooth continuous scrolling is to have two copies of the scrolling items. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72221695/infinite-autoplay-slider-ends-prematurely-and-doesnt-infinitely-loop/72221963#72221963 for example. Then you translateX by -50% rather than -100%.

Comment: This is actually what I'm trying to end with in the end. But I believe the "snapping" effect won't dissappear for the reasons described in the first answer. I'm trying to avoid JavaScript, but it's only coming to this.

Comment: There is no snapping in the answer in that link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `100%` is the size of the element, not the content. What I mean by this is because the content overflows the element, `100%` only refers to the visible width of the container.

You need to change `100%` to something else such as `150%`. Unfortunately, this means that you need to know the width of the contents before. The only other way that I know of is using JavaScript to calculate the width of the contents.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Some-guy258/pen/ZErBMRM)

Comment: For anyone caring for the final implementation. I wanted to keep it as less complicated as possible regarding JavaScript and keep the css intact. So I introduced a css variable for the actual scrolling width and then set it with JavaScript. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/efthymiosks/pen/QWQGVGg)