# My infinite autoplay carousel does not go back to the first picture

Tags: html, css

My infinite autoplay carousel does not go back to the first picture after the last one. I have 5 pictures and after the last one it's all white and there's a huge gap before it loops back to the first picture again. After the last image, there's like a few seconds before it goes back.[image before the last picture ends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0uwQ.png) [after the last image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvohB.png)

The following code:

```css
/* Animation */
@keyframes scroll {
    0% { transform: translateX(0); }
    100% { transform: translateX(calc(-250px * 7))}
}

/* Styling */.slider {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px; 
}

.slider::before,
    .slider::after {
        content: "";
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .slider::after {
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        transform: rotateZ(180deg);
    }

    .slider::before {
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    .slide-track {
        animation: scroll linear infinite;
        animation-duration: 30s;
        display: flex;
        width: calc(250px 14);
    }

    .slide {
        height: 200px;
        width: 250px;
        margin-right: 90px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide-track">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/ran.png" alt="" >
            <p>random name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/ran.png" alt="" />
            <p>random name/p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/ran.png"  alt=""  />
            <p>random name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/ran.png" alt=""  />
            <p>random name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="img/ran.png"  alt="" />
            <p>random name</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to change the animation duration and the width inside the slide-track, but nothing changed.

Comment: You need two copies.

Comment: and then? I tried putting two copies of my images and before my first copy ended the second one already started.

Comment: Regarding @AHaworth comment, see here for a working example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72221963/20896315

Comment: @A Haworth - I just saw that the example I linked to is even from you. Why didn't you post it? Very nice solution, upvoted.

Comment: I already got it! Thanks for the help everyone!!!  ^_^